# $match in mongoose won't query aggregated fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to query from a field from another collection:

```
const Order = require("../../models/orders");
const User = require("../../models/user");

module.exports = {
  async list(req, res) {
    const { page = 1, limit = 10 } = req.query;

    let filters = req.query;

    filters = {
      ...filters,
      page: undefined,
      limit: undefined
    };

    const myAggregate = Order.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "users",
          localField: "user",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "user"
        }
      },
      {
        $unwind: "$user"
      },
      {
        $match: { ...filters }
      },
      {
        $project: {
          coupon: 1,
          status: 1,
          "user._id": 1,
          "user.firstName": 1,
          "user.lastName": 1,
          currency: 1,
          rate: 1,
          amount: 1,
          subtotal: 1,
          total: 1,
          recipient: 1,
          createdAt: 1
        }
      }
    ]);

    const orders = await Order.aggregatePaginate(myAggregate, { page, limit });

    return res.send(orders);
  }
};
```

I'm using a plugin called `mongoose-aggregate-paginate-v2`, but it just add pagination to the mongoose array, so the problem is with the `$match`.

The collection `Orders` stores this object:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d447d49a910461fd3b5e155"),
    "coupon" : [],
    "status" : "Processing",
    "user" : ObjectId("5d35f67f1cf34e0018e36d69"),
    "currency" : "BRL",
    "rate" : 10640,
    "amount" : 30,
    "subtotal" : 30,
    "total" : 30,
    "recipient" : ObjectId("5d404b39f005f70419d89ae3"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-07-30T13:59:48.532Z")
}
```

Which, after the aggregation, turns this:

```
{
  "docs": [
    {
      "_id": "5d447d49a910461fd3b5e155",
      "coupon": [],
      "status": "Processing",
      "user": {
        "_id": "5d35f67f1cf34e0018e36d69",
        "firstName": "Boo",
        "lastName": "Foo"
      },
      "currency": "BRL",
      "rate": 10640,
      "amount": 30,
      "subtotal": 30,
      "total": 30,
      "recipient": "5d404b39f005f70419d89ae3",
      "createdAt": "2019-07-30T13:59:48.532Z"
    }
  ],
  "totalDocs": 1,
  "limit": 10,
  "page": 1,
  "totalPages": 1,
  "pagingCounter": 1,
  "hasPrevPage": false,
  "hasNextPage": false,
  "prevPage": null,
  "nextPage": null
}
```

Inside the `docs` is the array returned by `mongoose`. If I make a query of any of the `Orders` fields, the query returns successful, only with data that corresponds to the query. However, if I try to query the `firstName`, no matter how I try to format the `$match`, the query is an empty array.

How should I query aggregated fields?

Comment: (1) Do you've multiple users for same order(as I can see you're unwinding users)? (2) If you wish to use $skip & $limit, then no need to use another plugin..            (3) How did you get docs ? Can you give us  your unwind result or sample user docs & desired o/p

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying! (1) No, just one. (2)(3) I'm using another plugin for pagination. It just put the response array from `mongoose` to the docs array, and add those other fields related to pagination. Docs is the response array from mongoose. What I'm trying to do is query all orders from `Boo`

Comment: '{ $unwind: "$user"}' should be used if user is an array !!

Comment: It doesn't work with or without `$unwind`

Comment: Yes, if that query doesn't work, can you please give us more data : sample docs & desired o/p, that way we can solve it !!